# pub get failed (78; Invalid `PUB_HOSTED_URL=" https://pub.flutter-io.cn"`: invalid url: Scheme not starting with alphabetic character)

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, dart, game-development

At the start I was getting an error:

> `Got socket error trying to find package flutter_lints at https://pub.dartlang.org.`

I tried a solution that create a new environment variable

1. Create a new variable with the name: `PUB_HOSTED_URL` and assign value: `https://pub.flutter-io.cn`
2. Create a new variable with the name: `FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL` and assign value: `https://storage.flutter-io.cn`

It does not work, now I am getting new error:

> Invalid `PUB_HOSTED_URL=" https://pub.flutter-io.cn"`: invalid url: Scheme not starting with alphabetic character
> Running "flutter pub get" in my_card...
> pub get failed (78; Invalid `PUB_HOSTED_URL=" https://pub.flutter-io.cn"`: invalid url: Scheme not starting with
> alphabetic character)

Answer (score 2):

There is a space at first `PUB_HOSTED_URL=" https://pub.flutter-io.cn"`

Change this to `PUB_HOSTED_URL="https://pub.flutter-io.cn"`

Answer (score 0):

Set variable without any quotation marks like this:
in terminal type:

```
set PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.dartlang.org
```

to make sure it is set, use echo:

```
echo %PUB_HOSTED_URL%
```

then run `flutter pub get`

If this solution doesn't work, then
go to environment variables of windows,
in user variables,
edit `PUB_HOSTED_URL` to the correct url without any quotation marks .

Then restart Android Studio